# Is this the correct way of doing byte I/O?

Tags: io, binary, byte, ofstream, uint8t

I am trying to write bytes to a file in binary and I wrote this small test program to check whether I'm doing it correctly.

```
std::uint8_t F = 10111001;

std::ofstream K("C:/Users/WDR/Desktop/kml.enc", std::ios::binary);

for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    K << F;
}
```

The file is being written correctly. I'm getting a file of 256 bytes. However, when I see it in Hex Editor, each byte shows the value `00011001`. Am I doing something wrong? Or are bytes represented differently when seen in a Hex Editor? Please clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`10111001` is not a binary number. It's a decimal number. Assigning this number to an `uint8_t` will give you `10111001 % 256`, which is `25` or `11001` in binary.

you want to write `std::uint8_t F = 0xB9;`

Comment: So, if I'm reading from a file into a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`, should I add the `0x` prefix to every byte I read so that I write it correctly to another file? Also, what does `0x` mean and can it be used for binary representations also? If not, how would I write binary represented bytes into the file? Convert them to hex? Please clarify. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: the prefix `0x` in front of a number means it is a hexadecimal number. There is no prefix for binary numbers, so if you want to use a binary number in your c++ code, you have to use its hexadecimal representation with `0x` prefix, its octal representation with `0` prefix or its decimal representation with no prefix. But this is only a representation: `0xB9`, `185` and `0271` is the same number.

Comment: If you read from a file and write to another file you don't need to think about the base. Each computer has only binary numbers, your problem is the representation of the numbers in your c++ file. The `0b` prefix for binaries does not exist in c++, but in Java for example.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, @mch. I have tested it, and indeed, I don't need to worry about it in this case. However, what about the case where I have to write Huffman codes to the file? I am generating them within the C++ program and they are represented as strings of 0's and 1's. The entire file's encoding is in a `std::vector<bool>` from which I can accumulate them 8 bits at a time into a `std::uint8_t`. How do I write this `std::uint8_t` into the file? `std:hex` and then `std::showbase`?

Comment: I think you should simply write the value into the file, which have to be opened in binary mode. `std::hex` or `std::showbase` are for text outputs, not for binary files.

Comment: Will this work normally, though? Will I get back the same value I write when I read it for later decompression? Because if I do that, I will get the same problem as my initial question above. A character which holds a decimal value will be written to the file.